# Cannot convert from method group to System.Func<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm playing a bit with the .Net 4.0 Task class to download the google webpage in background using a thread. The problem is that if my function has 1 or more parameters, the application won't compile (idk how to pass that parameter). So I wonder how can I pass the function's parameter in the DoWork() method.

This works:

```
    public Task<String> DoWork() {
        //create task, of which runs our work of a thread pool thread
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<String>(this.DownloadString);

    }


    private String DownloadString()
    {
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
            return wc.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

This doesn't:

```
    public Task<String> DoWork() {
        //create task, of which runs our work of a thread pool thread
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<String>(this.DownloadString);

    }


    private String DownloadString(String uri)
    {
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
            return wc.DownloadString(uri);
    }
```

The error is:

```
cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Func<string>'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is your second snippet supposed to know what to download? Where are you passing the `uri` parameter?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, the problem is, I don't know how to pass it.

Comment: Well, that's what the compiler error is.. your `DownloadString` is not a `Func<string>`, it's a `Func<string,string>`. Task.StartNew is expecting the former, not the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.DownloadString("http://...."));
```

Comment: Delegate 'System.Func<string>' does not take 1 arguments

Comment: it works, thank you. It's kinda obvious, so simple. Since you answered first, I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 3):

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DownloadString("https://www.google.com"));
```

or

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (var wc = new WebClient())
                    return wc.DownloadString("https://www.google.com");
            });
```