# Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<string, string, bool>'

Tags: c#, .net

I am implementing a very simple rules engine that enforces some specifications dynamically at runtime.

The actual rules are stored in Tuples, and I have trouble storing a delegate to the `string.EndsWith` function.

The following code works for testing string equality, and returns `False` as expected (`"A"` is different from `"B"`):

```
var rule = new Tuple<string, Func<string, string, bool>, string>("A", string.Equals, "B");
Console.WriteLine(rule.Item2.Invoke(rule.Item1, rule.Item3));
```

However, I cannot figure out how to adapt this code to use the `string.EndsWith` function instead of `string.Equals`.

The following code does not compile and issues a `Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<string, string, bool>'` error message in Visual Studio.

```
var rule = new Tuple<string, Func<string, string, bool>, string>("A", string.EndsWith, "B");
Console.WriteLine(rule.Item2.Invoke(rule.Item1, rule.Item3));
```

I did search before asking this question, but I cannot understand the answers provided in [How do I fix 'compiler error - cannot convert from method group to System.Delegate'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479870/how-do-i-fix-compiler-error-cannot-convert-from-method-group-to-system-delega) or [Cannot convert from method group to System.Func<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376665/cannot-convert-from-method-group-to-system-funcstring). I do not see how to apply these to my problem.

Comment: Just look at the signature of the method.  None of them match the delegate, exactly as the error  message is telling you.

Comment: Also let start from `string.EndsWith` - there is no such method, i.e. the following does not compile `bool test = string.EndsWith("ABC", "C");`, right?

Comment: @Servy I thought the error message was telling me something different. But it makes sense now, you are right.

Comment: @IvanStoev You are perfectly right. I wrongly assumed the methods were following the same pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[String.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325(v=vs.110).aspx) and [String.EndsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) have different method signatures and must be called differently.

Specifically, String.Equals is static and takes two strings and returns a bool. String.EndsWith is an instance method taking one string and returns a bool

You can resolve your issue by wrapping the String.EndsWith call in a lambda to change the signature to take two strings and return a bool:

```
var rule = new Tuple<string, Func<string, string, bool>, string>
    ("AB", (string a, string b) => a.EndsWith(b), "B");
Console.WriteLine(rule.Item2.Invoke(rule.Item1, rule.Item3));
```

In general, the error means that there is no way the compiler can interpret `string.EndsWith` as a `Func<string, string, bool>`. You may find this [answer about what is a method group helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/886840/1316573) to understanding the error message.